# C#: Navigate through List<Customer> with Data-bound textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

After trying for hours, I am highly confused by the complex data binding concepts of wpf :-/

What is the simplest approach to show the properties of my business objects (e.g. Name, Street..) in a couple of textboxes?

Target is:

- User can navigate through the records (next, previous)
- Two-Way-Binding - Changes in textboxes should also change the values of the underlying propertys.

I already figured out how to bind the boxes to the properties, but how do I implement the navigation to the next/previous record?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look at ICollectionView methods.
Here's a working example:

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="myPeoples" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <local:Person Name="Bob Marley" Address="123 street" />
        <local:Person Name="Ted Nugent" Address="456 street" />
        <local:Person Name="Ron Paul" Address="789 street" />
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="cmdPrevious" Click="cmdPrevious_Click">Previous</Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdNext" Click="cmdNext_Click">Next</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{StaticResource myPeoples}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Address}" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

code behind:

```
private void cmdPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Person[] peoples = this.FindResource("myPeoples") as Person[];
    System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(peoples);
    collectionView.MoveCurrentToPrevious();

}

private void cmdNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Person[] peoples = this.FindResource("myPeoples") as Person[];
    System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(peoples);
    collectionView.MoveCurrentToNext();
}
```